System nanoTime() has two trailing zeros
I have written some code using System.nanoTime() and the output did always have two trailing zeros. Now I wondered if that behavior is normal. I tried it on two laptops and it always stayed that inprecise, even though I remember having seen a particular precise value of System.nanoTime() somewhere in the past.
Here´s the code:
        long beginTime = System.nanoTime();

        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            // doing something for time to pass
            long tpValue = 1;
            for (int j = 0; j < 14862; j++) {
                long value = 0x4b38e;
                value &= System.nanoTime();
                tpValue = (tpValue & value) | (tpValue ^ value);
            }
            long timePassed = System.nanoTime() - beginTime;
            System.out.println("Time passed: " + timePassed + " ns;" +
                    " Value calculated to pass time: " + tpValue);
        }

In this example on my device the value of tpValue would always be the same unless I divide System.nanoTime() by 1000.
Here the output:
 Time passed: 921000 ns; Value calculated to pass time: 308109
 Time passed: 9554500 ns; Value calculated to pass time: 308109
 Time passed: 10551800 ns; Value calculated to pass time: 308109
 Time passed: 11530700 ns; Value calculated to pass time: 308109
 Time passed: 12519400 ns; Value calculated to pass time: 308109


probably you are using Windows - I can reproduce on Windows (nanoTime() always returning two trailing zeros), but not on Unix

The only thing you can derive from this is that the resolution of the timer used in your Java version, the OS, or your computer hardware seems to have a resolution of (at most) 100 nanoseconds, possibly multiples of 100 nanoseconds.

From https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#nanoTime--

This method provides nanosecond precision, but not necessarily
nanosecond resolution (that is, how frequently the value changes) - no
guarantees are made except that the resolution is at least as good as
that of currentTimeMillis().

Also your test has a few flaws, you're not polling nanotime very often. You basically have only 5 meaningful calls to long timePassed = System.nanoTime() - beginTime;
And you're not looking at System.nanoTime() directly, but at a difference of 2 System.nanoTime() values.
If you want to test resolution you can do any of the following
1.test your hypothesis that all values have a trailing 00 or same last 2 digits:
while(true) {
   long time = System.nanoTime();
   if(time % 100 != 0) {
       System.out.println(time)
   }
}

2.Or you can print the difference between a lot of call values, afterwards can filter all multiples of the smallest value with % and see if that is the actual resolution:
while(true) {
   long time = System.nanoTime();
   System.out.println(System.nanoTime()-time);
}


I was testing System.nanoTime() in a different project before I wrote the code above. So the code I added here is only there for purposes of quick semi-testing and for the question. I can see the point you were making in how proper testing requires a different approach.

The Answer by HopefullyHelpful is correct and smart.
I can add my own pedestrian simple code showing counts of nanoseconds to the singles place.
for ( int i = 1 ; i <= 10 ; i ++ )
{
    System.out.println( System.nanoTime() ) ;
}

See this code run at Ideone.com.
15463866040482559
15463866041067009
15463866041111618
15463866041153989
15463866041196195
15463866041238231
15463866041279697
15463866041321311
15463866041362851
15463866041404462

And, by the way, to calculate elapsed nanos, I would use the handy Duration class.
long start = System.nanoTime() ;
…
Duration d = Duration.ofNanos( System.nanoTime() - start ) ; 
System.out.println( d ) ;  // Duration#toString generates text in standard ISO 8601 format. 
System.out.println( d.toNanos() ) ;


PT0.000843285S
843285

